# CSS - Make Small Centered Responsive youtube Video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fix a CSS bug on my website. I'm currently using bootstrap framework and I'm trying to make a responsive video.

When I do this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3Vkma-S35Y4?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> 
  </iframe>
```

My video is in the correct position (centered), and it is in the right width and eight, BUT is not responsive

If then I try to fix using the bootstrap classes, using:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

The video is now responsive, but is too big , if I try to resize it, it doesn't stay at the correct position.

How can I fix that?

Comment: set max-width and max-height for iframe and add text-aligh:center;

Comment: I tried, but look what happened: http://prntscr.com/8j3sb5

Comment: found a solution by now?, you could accept an answer of post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need a container that:

1. has the `center-text` class
2. act as a container to set dimension eg: `col-md-x`

i just post some code from my latest work here to give you a idea:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 right-border">
  <div class="detail-image text-center">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/waSnKOK_f3M?rel=0?html5=1"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `col-sm-4` gives dimension so the responsive video has some boundaries to obey

Answer (score 0):

You can set `max-width:" ";` and `max-height:" ";`